# Firebase Cloud Functions // Snapshot has no readTime

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting strange warning messages in my Firebase Cloud Functions logs:

```
Snapshot has no readTime. Using now()
```

I have quite a number of functions running and it happens with a good handful of them. But it doesn't happen with each invocation, just occasionally.

A google search turned up the line responsible for this message in the `snapshotConstructor` function within the `firebase-functions` lib. You can [find it on Github here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/6d146aa5604c899f21b19a749b8e6663bddef697/src/providers/firestore.ts#L165). It seems like the `data.value.readTime` isn't available on the `Event`.

What exactly is causing this error and is it a problem?

---

UPDATE: I've discovered this is happening when `onWrite` functions are triggered at the same time by the same document. I have a few functions that start like this:

```
functions
.firestore.document('organizations/{organizationId}/updates/{updateId}')
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {...
```

Again, it doesn't happen every time they're triggered, but often enough to warrant concern.

Comment: You post should show the code that generates the error and highlight exactly which line you have traced to be the problem - do not link to outside sources.  We should be able to copy it into a new project and observe what you're seeing.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I'm not sure a minimal reproducible example is applicable in this case. The message doesn't come with a stack trace, so I can't identify which line in my code is causing it. In fact, it's happening with quite a number of functions which are all very different. I have to imagine it's an error within the function runner itself, right?

Comment: A minimal repo is **exactly** the thing you need to produce here.  We need to narrow this down to the bare minimum so we have an idea of where this message could possibly come from.  If it could come from anywhere in a large stack of tech, that's likely not going to get a solution here - no one will bother to look into it.

Comment: I understand, @DougStevenson. However, the nature of the warning is that it's not caused by anything within the function itself and is unreliably reproducible. It's happening in production at random which is the concerning part. The notices started showing up suddenly on Feb 28 1PM CST. It's happening to `onWrite` functions that are triggered by the same document update. I assume the only way to reproduce this issue would be deploy several `onWrite` functions pointing to the same collection and then triggering them in rapid succession hoping that eventually the warning will show up.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, this isn't something Stack Overflow can help you with.  It sounds like what you have is at best a bug report to send to Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: Got it. I'll try there.

Comment: @CDoe were you able to track this down?

Comment: This seems to happen in Firestore `onWrite` listener, when a document is deleted (onWrite is called for create/update/delete).

(1) onWrite calls changeConstructor
(2) changeConstructor calls snapshotConstructor
(3) snapshotConstructor calls logger.warn('Snapshot has no readTime. Using now()');
when data.value.readTime doesn't exist (and since the doc was just deleted, this doesn't exist?)

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/139e1d94d585c26a5d76586685a976a5643df869/src/providers/firestore.ts#L165

Comment: Please accept @anothermh 's answer. It's correct. He clearly didn't need a code snippet to tell us what the issue is...

Answer (score 4):

Firestore used to have a soft-limit of 1 write per second for a single document. [This soft-limit has been removed from the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74455395/3784008) but there is still information such as [the Firebase documentation on read/write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#read_and_write_operations):

> #### Read and write operations
>
> - The exact maximum rate that an app can update a single document depends highly on the workload. For more information, see [Updates to a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document).

That link points to documentation that provides [warnings about writing to a single document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document):

> #### Updates to a single document
>
> As you design your app, consider how quickly your app updates single documents. The best way to characterize your workload's performance is to perform load testing. The exact maximum rate that an app can update a single document depends highly on the workload. Factors include the write rate, contention among requests, and the number affected indexes.
>
> A document write operation updates the document and any associated indexes, and Firestore synchronously applies the write operation across a quorum of replicas. **At high enough write rates, the database will start to encounter contention, higher latency, or other errors.**

That's what's happening here:

1. You have multiple writes to a single document in a very short period of time
2. You have onWrite-triggered functions that are firing in response to these events
3. Firestore is attempting to acquire information about the document being written but due to a race condition caused by the high write rate to the single document it is unable to do so
4. The error is then surfaced in the logs

The solution is that you need to limit the write-rate to a single document. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74455395/3784008) explains that the [key visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/key-visualizer) should be used to identify hotspots in your application's read/write behavior to limit these issues. Otherwise you will continue to see the *contention, higher latency, or other errors* mentioned in the documentation.