# Has firestore removed the soft limit of 1 write per second to a single document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has always had a soft limit of 1 write per second to a single document. That meant that for doing things like a counter that updates more frequently than once per second, the recommended solution was sharded counters.

Looking at the [Firestore Limits documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions), this limit appears to have disappeared. The Firebase summit presentation mentioned that Firestore is now more scalable, but only mentioned *hard limits* being removed.

Can anyone confirm whether this limit has indeed been removed, and we can remove all our sharded counters in favor of writing to a single `count` document tens or hundreds of times per second?

Comment: Relevant web archive of the page in question: [Usage and Limits - Firestore](https://web.archive.org/web/20221013230748/https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This was indeed removed from the documentation. It was always a soft limit that was not enforced in the code, but instead an estimate for the physical limitation of how long it takes to synchronize the changes to indexes and multiple data center.

We've significantly improved the infrastructure used for these write operations, and now provide tools such a the [key visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/key-visualizer) to better analyze performance and look for hot spots in the read and write behavior of your app. While there's still some physical limit, we recommend using these tools rather than depending on a single documented value to analyze your app's database performance.

For most use-cases I'd recommend using the new [`COUNT()` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) nowadays. But if you want to continue using write-time aggregation counters, it is still recommended to use a sharded counter for high-volume count operations, we've just stopped giving a hard number for when to use it.

Comment: Is there a queue or pooling system so that 10 write events sent almost at the same time do not deteriorate the firestore database? It would be nice to know how many is too many, roughly speaking. Thanks!

Comment: Bulk writes you mean? https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/bulkwriter

Comment: would Bulk writes work on a single document? The point of writing a document many times instead of once, would be to trigger some firestore listener for each change.